# R: scatterplot() from car package, how to add point labels?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to scatterplot two variables with point labels (a label for each data point). One can do this with plot() and textxy() among others, but I like the scatterplot() function from the car package. However, I can't figure out how to use it.

```
library(car)
test.x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6) #x var data
test.y = test.x*2 #x var data
test.labels = c("a","b","c","d","e","f") #labels
scatterplot(test.y ~ test.x, labels=as.vector(test.labels),smooth=F) #plot
```

It plots it without errors, but there are no labels.

Using textxy() works, but since scatterplot() draws differently than plot() the labels and datapoints are displaced.

Comment: You got to set `id.n`, too. E.g. `scatterplot(test.y ~ test.x, labels=test.labels,smooth=F, id.n = length(test.labels))` to plot all labels.

Comment: Thank you. That works. Although that parameter seems completely pointless to me.

Comment: I've never used the function until I saw your post, but I guess, the param can be handy to avoid clutter. Anyway, I make an answer that you can check, so we can put this question ad acta.

Comment: I spent hours googling the issue. Reading the documentation didn't help me. I guess I somehow skipped over the line about the arguments: "id.method,id.n,id.cex,id.col".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to set `id.n`, too. E.g.

```
scatterplot(test.y ~ test.x, labels=test.labels,smooth=F, id.n = length(test.labels))
```

to plot all labels.